# Global solutions for linear PDE using behavior outside bounded region

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Suppose we have a linear first-order PDE of the form $$\sum _{i=1}^{n}a_{i}(x_{1},\dots ,x_{n}){\frac {\partial u}{\partial x_{i}}}=c(x_{1},\dots ,x_{n},u)$$
where $c$ and each $a_i$ are smooth functions such that 
$$ \left . \begin{align}
|a_i(x_1,\ldots,x_n)| &\leq \|(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\| \\
 c(x_1,\ldots,x_n) &= 0 \end{align} \ \ \right\} \text{ for } \|(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\| > R \gg 0.$$
Does such a system necessarily have global solutions?

*Note:* Outside the ball of radius $R$, the function $u=0$ is a solution. However, it's unclear to me whether I can get local solutions inside the ball that patch together with each other and vanish as the radius approaches $R$.